# ggplot: conflict between geom_text and ggplot(fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use geom_text on a ggplot, there is a conflict with the ggplot "fill" option.

Here is a clear example of the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
a=ChickWeight
str(a)
xx=data.frame(level=levels(a$Chick),letter=1:50)

# a graph with the fill option alone
x11();ggplot(a, aes(x=Chick, y=weight,fill=Diet))  + geom_boxplot(notch=F) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=23, size=3, fill="white") +
xlab("Chick") +
ylab("Weight")

# a graph with the geom_text option alone
x11();ggplot(a, aes(x=Chick, y=weight))  + geom_boxplot(notch=F) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=23, size=3, fill="white") +
geom_text(data=xx, aes(x=level,y=450,label = letter)) +
xlab("Chick") +
ylab("Weight")

# a graph with the two option
x11();ggplot(a, aes(x=Chick, y=weight,fill=Diet))  + geom_boxplot(notch=F) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=23, size=3, fill="white") +
geom_text(data=xx, aes(x=level,y=1750,label = letter)) +
xlab("Chick") +
ylab("Weight")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the fill to affect the boxplot, move the aes() into the boxplot. Any `aes()` aesthetics in the `ggplot()` call itself will be propagated to all layers

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=Chick, y=weight))  + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Diet), notch=F) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=23, size=3, fill="white") +
geom_text(data=xx, aes(x=level,y=1750,label = letter)) +
xlab("Chick") +
ylab("Weight")
```

you can also disable the `fill=` aesthetic in the text layer with `fill=NULL`

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=Chick, y=weight, fill=Diet))  + geom_boxplot(notch=F) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=23, size=3, fill="white") +
geom_text(data=xx, aes(x=level,y=1750,label = letter, fill=NULL)) +
xlab("Chick") +
ylab("Weight")
```